# Why can I access a nested object when deconstructing without the dot notation unless there is another nested object with the same name?

Tags: javascript, scope

> why can I access the object openingHours if it is only in the

```
const restaurant = {

  openingHours: {
    thu: {
      open: 12,
      close: 22,
    },
    fri: {
      open: 11,
      close: 23,
    },
    sat: {
      open: 0, // Open 24 hours
      close: 24,
    },
  },
};


const newObject = {
  a: 1,
  openingHours: {
    fri: {
      open: 7,
      close: 7,
    },
  },
};
```

> I need the dot notation if there is a nested openingHours object in both newObject and restaurant.

```
const {
  fri: { open, close },
} = restaurant.openingHours;
```

> But if the openingHours is in the restaurant object only, I can access using only openingHours instead of restaurant.openingHours

```
const restaurant = {

  openingHours: {
    thu: {
      open: 12,
      close: 22,
    },
    fri: {
      open: 11,
      close: 23,
    },
    sat: {
      open: 0, // Open 24 hours
      close: 24,
    },
  },
};


const {
  fri: { open, close },
} = openingHours;
```

> Why does this work? Shouldn't openingHours not be in the available scope chain unless it's called with the dot notation restaurant.openingHours?

> I appreciate any help in explaining this, as it's pretty confusing to me.

Comment: "*But if the openingHours is in the restaurant object only, I can access using only `openingHours` instead of `restaurant.openingHours`*" I don't think you can do that. Did you define a variable called `openingHours` at somewhere else?

Comment: No, that is actually my code from inside Visual Studio. I compiled it and it ran without bugs. I printed out the values to the console to check and the assignment worked correctly.